# How to make List with Infinite Nested subcategories using MVC asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nested, categories

My Client Required me to make some categories with 7 sub categories, i made it, but the output does show "OutMemoryException", i tried it, but the output it does show one category without subcategories

I Have Some code like this

Controller :

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {      var listcategoryparent = new List<ArticleCategoryList>();
        var parentcategorylist = _articleCategoryBs.GetListMainCategory(0);
        foreach (var parent in parentcategorylist)
        {
            var categoryparent = new ArticleCategoryList();
            var listcategorychild1 = new List<ArticleCategoryList>();

            foreach (var item1 in _articleCategoryBs.GetListMainCategory(parent.ArticleCategoryId))
            {
                var categoryChild1 = new ArticleCategoryList();
                var listcategorychild2 = new List<ArticleCategoryList>();

                foreach (var item2 in _articleCategoryBs.GetListMainCategory(item1.ArticleCategoryId))
                {
                    var categoryChild2 = new ArticleCategoryList();
                    var listcategorychild3 = new List<ArticleCategoryList>();

                    foreach (var item3 in _articleCategoryBs.GetListMainCategory(item2.ArticleCategoryId))
                    {
                        var categoryChild3 = new ArticleCategoryList();
                        var listcategorychild4 = new List<ArticleCategoryList>();

                        foreach (var item4 in _articleCategoryBs.GetListMainCategory(item3.ArticleCategoryId))
                        {
                            var categoryChild4 = new ArticleCategoryList();
                            var listcategorychild5 = new List<ArticleCategoryList>();
                            var listCategoryChild5 = _articleCategoryBs.GetListMainCategory(item4.ArticleCategoryId);

                            foreach (var item5 in listCategoryChild5)
                            {
                                var categoryChild5 = new ArticleCategoryList();
                                var listcategorychild6 = new List<ArticleCategoryList>();
                                var listCategoryChild6 = _articleCategoryBs.GetListMainCategory(item5.ArticleCategoryId);

                                foreach (var item6 in listCategoryChild6)
                                {
                                    var categoryChild6 = new ArticleCategoryList();
                                    var listcategorychild7 = new List<ArticleCategoryList>();
                                    var listCategoryChild7 =_articleCategoryBs.GetListMainCategory(item6.ArticleCategoryId);

                                    foreach (var item7 in listCategoryChild7)
                                    {
                                        var categoryChild7 = new ArticleCategoryList();
                                        categoryChild7.parrent = item7;
                                        categoryChild7.Child = listcategorychild7;
                                        listcategorychild7.Add(categoryChild7);
                                    }
                                    categoryChild6.parrent = item6;
                                    categoryChild6.Child = listcategorychild6;
                                    listcategorychild6.Add(categoryChild6);
                                }
                                categoryChild5.parrent = item5;
                                categoryChild5.Child = listcategorychild5;
                                listcategorychild5.Add(categoryChild5);
                            }
                            categoryChild4.parrent = item4;
                            categoryChild4.Child = listcategorychild4;
                            listcategorychild4.Add(categoryChild4);
                        }
                       categoryChild3.parrent = item3;
                        categoryChild3.Child = listcategorychild3;
                        listcategorychild3.Add(categoryChild3);
                    }
                    categoryChild2.parrent = item2;
                    categoryChild2.Child = listcategorychild2;
                    listcategorychild2.Add(categoryChild2);
                }
                categoryChild1.parrent = item1;
                categoryChild1.Child = listcategorychild2;
                listcategorychild1.Add(categoryChild1);
            }
            categoryparent.parrent = parent;
            categoryparent.Child = listcategorychild1;
            listcategoryparent.Add(categoryparent);
        }
        ViewBag.ListCategory1 = listcategoryparent;
        return View(listArtikel.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

My Services Function File (ArticlesCategoryBussinessService.cs) :

```
public List<ArticleCategory> GetListMainCategory(int parent)
        {
            List<ArticleCategory> result = _dBtsics.ArticleCategory
                .Where(p => p.Parent == parent && p.Status == 1)
                .ToList();

            return result;
        }
```

My Model File (ArticlesCategory.cs) :

```
[Table("ArticleCategory")]
public class ArticleCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int ArticleCategoryId { get; set; }
    public int Parent { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleCategoryList
{
    public ArticleCategory parrent { get; set; }
    public List<ArticleCategoryList> Child { get; set; }
}}
```

And this is My Views (_partCategory.cshtml)

```
   @helper showCategories(dynamic categories)
        {
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        foreach (var item1 in categories)
        {
                <ul id="sidebar-nav" class="nav d-flex flex-column accordion-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="fa fa-1x fa-angle-right float-right mt-1"></a>
                        <a data-active_nav="summary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#child-@i-@(j+1)" class="nav-link collapsed inline"><span>@item1.parrent.Name</span></a>
                        <div data-parent="#sidebar-nav" id="child-@i-@(j+1)" class="is-child collapse">
                            @if (item1.Child != null)
                            {
                                showCategories(item1.Child);
                            }
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            }   
        }

@showCategories(ViewBag.ListCategory1)
```

My Database Schema :

[image]

Comment: why is your question titled "infinite" when you are talking about exactly 7? the solution might change, depending on whether you do have to support infinite levels.

Comment: okay sorry for my mistake, i mean 7

Comment: fix for 7 sub categories other wise infinite loop